# Javascript: Trying to delete options from select in a loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove options from a `select` inside a `loop`. The idea is that when the user adds a quantity to the booking the selects quantity will decrease depending on how many rooms have been selected which is why it's in a loop. I put an alert inside it and it is indeed looping the correct amount of time it just isn't removing the `options`.

The issue is that it just isn't removing anything, checked `variables` and they are all as expected. Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is the code I currently have for this:

```
//example variables
var quantity = 3;
var row = 2;
for (var i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
var el_to_remove = $('.quantity_rooms_row_'+row+' option').last();
el_to_remove.remove();
}
```

Comment: You could simplify: `$('.quantity_rooms_row'+row+' option').slice(-quantity).remove();` - that is assuming all else is working.

Comment: I'll give this a go, if it doesn't work I'll give everything another check over and report back, thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var quantity = 3;
var row = 2;
for (var i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
  var el_to_remove = $('.orange'+row).last();
  el_to_remove.remove();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
<select>
  <option value="orange1" class="orange1">Orange 1</option>
  <option value="orange2" class="orange2">Orange 2</option>
  <option value="orange3" class="orange3">Orange 3</option>
  <option value="orange4" class="orange4">Orange 4</option>
</select>

</html>
```

Comment: This is working, thanks to everyone for their replies, greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

give me your plunker or fiddle i will correct otherwise you can see array methods there are methods in javascript by which you can remove the elements from an array like splice and pop

**1.splice** --:
Adds/Removes elements from an array
syntax:`array.splice(index,howmany,item1,.....,itemX).`

**2.pop** --:
Removes the last element of an array, and returns that element.

syntax:`yourArray.pop();`